# Get current database name - cakephp 3

Tags: php, cakephp

I need to get current and default DB name in cakephp 3.

I know how its possible in cakephp 2 but cannot get a work around for cakephp 3.
I have looked into the cakephp library in datasource/connectionManager.php but still i cant get any method to use.
Can you please help me out in finding out the current connections config details?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: "_current_" is a rather vague term (similar applies to "_default_", unless you are referring to a connection named "default"), as there's only a "current" database in the model/table find/query context, and even there a single find, even a single query, might point to multiple different databases. So you may want to elaborate on what exactly you mean by "_current_"!

Comment: "current" here is the DB on which I am calling a model class. I can create multiple DB's on the Fly. So I want database name for the one used currently. Lets just say, for now I can have only default DB name.

Comment: $SomeModel->connection()->configName()

Comment: @ADmad This gives me current connection name. I need current database name used. for eg: $SomeModel->connection()->configName() gives me 'default'. I need database used inside 'default'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found my answer after looking into some of the core cakephp files. Plus ADmad's answer gave me a hint. I found two ways of doing it.

**Method 1:** Using Current model Object.

```
$this->{$modelName}->connection()->config();
```

will give config, and,

```
$this->{$modelName}->connection()->config()['database'];
```

will give the current Database name.

**Method 2:** Using Datasource Object.

```
$dataSourceObject = ConnectionManager::get($connectionName); // $connectionName can be 'default'
```

Config: `$dataSourceObject->config();`

Current Database name: `$dataSourceObject->config()['database'];`

Comment: Yes my earlier comment was mainly meant as a hint to give you an idea of how to get connection instance. That's why it was a comment not an answer :)

Comment: Thanks for the Hint :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're on older version of CakePHP (mine is 2.4.6), you can also use:

```
ConnectionManager::$config->default['database']
```

and you can load ConnectionManager via:

```
App::uses('ConnectionManager', 'Model');
```